# How to await multiple async await requests in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I am wanting to do something like the following in a React component:

```
const someArray = [/*stuff*/]
const results = []
someArray.forEach(async item => {

  const result = await someAsyncFunction(item)
  results.push(result)
})
```

How can I know when all the results have returned then do something?

If I was using $q, in AngularJS, I could do

```
var results = []
someArray.forEach(function(item) {
  var result = someAsyncFunctionThatReturnsAPromise(item);
  results.push(result);
});

$q.all(results).then(function() {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: use `Promise.all(/* Your Promise Array */).then(...)`?

Comment: You're making your code synchronous, so isn't the order of operations guaranteed? Meaning that if you put `console.log(results)` after your forEach loop, it would have all the values. That's the beauty of async/await.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda  Unfortunately you can't use forEach with async / await, but a basic for loop will work..

Comment: @Keith Ah, okay thanks I didn't know that. OP check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: As @CRice said but you will have to remove the `async` `await`

Comment: You have a couple of options,.  replace forEach with a normal for loop.  Use `Promise.all`, but do be aware Promise.all can cause performance issues on big arrays, due to thrashing.  I personally think a Promise compatible  map like Bluebirds http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html is the most flexible, due to the concurrency option.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you *can* `await Promise.all()`.

Comment: @hayavuk `If I'm not mistaken`,.. Indeed your not mistaken, you can use `await` on anything that returns a promise, and Promise.all returns a Promise..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd do exactly the same thing as if it wasn't a React component:

```
Promise.all(someArray.map(someAsyncFunction)).then(results => {
  // do stuff with results
});
```

Of course you can also use [`q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), which `$q` is based on. It's up to you.

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up using the q library.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from Felix, inside an `async` function, you can also `await` on the results from `Promise.all()`, so:

```
const results = await Promise.all(someArray.map(someAsyncFunction));
```